# Retornando propriedades de um array de objetos com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um menu de um restaurante e ao clicar no botão calcular, retornar o pedido do cliente e suas informações. No entanto, quando clico em calcular, o output retorna com todos os objetos, sendo que quero apenas aquele que o cliente insere.

```
let prods = [
{id: 1, name: "Bife com batata", price: 30.0},
{id: 2, name: "Coxa de frango crocante", price: 25.0},
{id: 3, name: "Carne de panela", price: 22.0},
{id: 4, name: "Farofa", price: 10.0},
{id: 5, name: "Mini salada", price: 8.0},
{id: 6, name: "Torresmo", price: 12.0},
];

function calc(){
let quantities = document.getElementsByName("quantity");

let output = document.getElementById("output");
let total = 0;

let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL',
});

let personlData = document.getElementById("nome");
personlData = personlData.value;

output.innerHTML = "";

for (let input of quantities) {
    let id = input.id;

    total += prods[id-1].price * parseFloat(input.value);

    output.innerHTML += `<p>Caro ${personlData}, Seguem as informações do seu pedido.</p>
    <p>O seu pedido é: </p>
    Prato: ${prods[id-1].name} - Preço: ${prods[id-1].price} - Qauntidade: ${input.value}<br>
    Preço final: ${total}`

}

}
```